# Convert char hex to char dec in C

Tags: c

I want to convert a value stored in a variable type `unsigned char` as a decimal in this way:

```
unsigned char hexValue = 0x0C;
```

And I want to convert `hexValue` into a new `unsigned char` in "dec" format like this:

```
unsigned char decValue = 0x12; //Ox0C
```

I tried `sprintf()` and `strtol()` but without good results.

Comment: This thing doesn't make any sense. There's some serious confusion about what a value and its representations are.

Comment: `0x0c` and `0x12` are 2 different values. `0x0c` is 12 in base 10, `0x12` is 18 in base 10. There's only 1 value no matter how it's printed out. The format specifier of `printf` is how you pick how the value is displayed (when using `printf` to display it).

Comment: Values are stored in binary. It is their representation for humans, that varies.

Comment: You can add 6 `0x0C + 0x06 = 0x12`

Comment: What (unsatisfactory) results do you get with what code and what input?

Comment: Just leave off `0x`. `unsigned char decValue = 12; // 0x0C`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it can get confusing understanding the difference between value and representation.  So, consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char hexVal = 0x0C;
    unsigned char dec = hexVal;
    printf("\nValue expressed in decimal: %d and in hexadecimal: %x", dec,dec);
    return 0;
}
```

See [live code](https://ideone.com/0zBpZ2)

It expresses the notion of ten as a hexadecimal in the first assignment statement.   When hexVal is assigned to variable dec what is assigned is the value ten which is stored in a binary format.  Since dec is already a variable, no need for sprintf() here.  You may then use the format specifier to express the value of ten as a decimal or in another base.  In this case. The value is a expressed as a decimal.